# Unable to update openscript

Tags: eclipse, openscript

Just started to learn how to use the `openscript`, and was thinking to update it. While it is updating, a dialog pop stated that:

```
OpenScript ASReplay Build (2.6.5.287) requires plug-in "oracle.oats.asreplay.lib".
```

It won't let me proceed to the next. Any Idea how to get the plug in? Or get rid of that error and update the `openscript` successfully ?

`Openscript` version: Version: `12.5.0.1 Build 287`

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to update it using the `Eclipse` update sites; `Openscript` is an extention of `Eclipse`, not a plugin.

Download the latest `Openscript` version from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/downloads/index-084446.html)

Currently (downloaded a few days ago) i am on `12.5.0.2 Build 537`

Answer (score 0):

It can be resolved by disable the asreplay in

- Help > Software Updates > Manage Configuration
- Expand the tree >look for asreply >disable it
- Openscript restarts