# openscript asreplay build (2.6.5.287) requires plug-in "oracle.oats.asreplay.lib

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, openscript

I am not able to install any plugin in OpenScript version 12.5.0.1 .
I am getting error `OpenScript ASReplay Build (2.6.5.287) requires plug-in "oracle.oats.asreplay.lib"`. Can anyone help me? I have to use only this version.

Comment: Which Eclipse plug-in are you trying to install?

Comment: You have not provided enough information to help you. If you are attempting to use OpenScript you should only use the installer provided from Oracle. This [recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31589122/1389658) explains. Are you trying to enhance the Openscript you have installed with an Eclipse plug-in, or only use native Openscript?

Comment: I have created my own plug-in and installed in eclipse but it's not showing in window->preferences and window->show view

Comment: Does the same plug-in work in real install of Eclipse? You should test your plug-in in Eclipse install, not Openscript.

Comment: Yes.The plug-in which I have created working in Eclipse .I have tested in Eclipse sdk4.4 where I had built this plug-in .Now I am having another issue  like when I have installed in eclipse its showing in file->new other but not showing in window-->show view or window -->preferences.

Comment: Well you should edit your question to include these details. Someone may be able to help (not me). Consider that Openscript is an extension of Eclipse 3.4.1 not version 4.4 which your plug-in is built.

Answer (score 1):

- Help > Software Updates > Manage Configuration
- Expand the tree > Find OpenScript ASReplay Build 2.6.5.287 > Disable it
  Openscript restarts and you're free to install new plugins now.

Comment: what is about asReplay??what functionality it does??if I disable will it not reflect while play back and recording??

Comment: Related to Oracle Fusion/ADF element. If you're using that then you might be out of luck